# Open another activity by clicking to ListViewItem and pass text and image.

Tags: java, android, listview

To make it easier for you to understand, what I'm trying to make is a app which shows me a list of books - name of the book and image of front cover. When clicked on, it will go to another activity, with an enlarged image of the cover and description of the book. It Should be scrollable. 
This is how much I have.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
TextView select;
String[] items = { "Naruto", "One Piece", "Bleach", "Harry Potter", "Vampire's Assistant",
        "Pet Cemetery" };

/** Called with the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle a) {
    super.onCreate(a);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
    select = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    select.setText(items[position]);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/selection"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ListView
     android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use intent to pass the text to the next activity

Comment: It is a common practice to accept one of the answers if it helped you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
    i.putExtra("book_position", position);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

ActivityTwo(in onCreate or wherever you feel comfortable):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null && extras.getInt("book_position", 0) > 0) {
   int bookPosition = extras.getInt("book_position");
   // Do something with the position. E.g. retrieve the data from the String array in this position and populate a TextView/ImageView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityToStart.class).putExtra("book", items[position]));
}
```

Then in ActivityToStart

```
  public class ActivityToStart  {
    private String bookName;
    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle bundleSavedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(bundleSavedInstance);
        getIntentExtras();
    }
    public void getIntentExtras(){
      this.bookName = getIntent().getExtra().getString("book");
    }


}
```